# Including a certain header file causes errors from SFML

Tags: c++, sfml, chaiscript

I'm trying to use ChaiScript with SFML for my game engine. All the SFML stuff works fine, until I include `chaiscript.hpp` in my game object header file. My GameObject header file looks a little like this:

```
#include <a bunch of standard libraries>
#include "imgui.h"

struct Object {
    std::string name;

    void init();
    void update();
    void render();

    *some template functions*
};
```

The problem occurs when I try to include `chaiscript.hpp` in the above file. I get a repeating error (8 of them, to be exact) from SFML's Rect.inl file: `'(': illegal token on right side of '::'`, and then no other errors. It compiles fine when I don't include `chaiscript.hpp`, or when I include `chaiscript.hpp` in the object cpp file. I've used ChaiScript before with SDL and never had an issue like this, so is it an SFML macro messing something up? How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like something in ChaiScript is messing up something in SFML. Reversing the order that you include them may remove those errors (include SFML before ChaiScript, or vice versa).